# How to add Kendo WYSIWYG Editor to a Kendo UI Grid Column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wysiwyg, kendo-grid

I have a ASP.NET MVC Kendo UI Grid bound to a model. I added a new string property called "Info" to my model. While adding new item or editing an existing item using Kendo Grid, I want to display the "Info" property as a WYSIWYG editor.

I am not sure how to do that.

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and it was pretty easy. On the edit event of Kendo Grid, I had to initialize the property id with KendoEditor as below.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    $("#Info").kendoEditor();
}
```